# Azure automation - How to use export-csv in azure automation using portal

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azureportal

I am trying to automate a small PS script. The script checks the version of powershell used for azure and writes the details to csv file to my local folder.

I am using runbook on azure portal itself. I am getting the details with no issues. but I cannot write the details to csv files. I also checked the path provided to store csv file is valid.

[image]

What is the way out to generate a csv file using azure runbook using portal itself ?

Comment: Are you trying to write to the C: drive on your PC or the C: drive of the Azure Automation instance where your script is running?

Answer (score 4):

Runbooks run in a host managed by Azure Automation and not your local machine unless you are using a [hybrid runbook worker](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker/).  If you have not remoted to another machine in your script, the PowerShell you wrote will generate the file on the Azure Automation host and will be lost after your job completes.

You could fix this by creating the file on the Azure Automation host like you do in your sample and then copying it to an VM that you want to store the CSV on.  You can use [this sample](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Copy-a-File-to-an-Azure-VM-d2ad9e1f) to do the copy.  I'm not sure what your use case is here, but you may also want to consider just storing it in blob storage.